# C# - form combo box snapping closed

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have a winform built in Visual Studio and C#. Up until recently, the combo boxes behaved as expected. However, while adding functionality, I moved all the form elements around and now two of the combo boxes snap closed before an option can be selected (although you can select an item with the scroll wheel or arrow keys). The code in the dropdown event hasn't changed. I'm at a loss - anyone encountered anything like this?

Here's the code of the dropdown event: -

```
    void comboBoxTargetServer_DropDown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxTargetServer.Items.Clear();
        comboBoxTargetDatabase.Items.Clear();
        comboBoxTargetDatabase.Items.Add("");
        comboBoxTargetDatabase.Enabled = false;
        //ActiveForm.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        List<string> sqlServers = SQLUtilities.ListSQLServers();
        sqlServers.Sort();
        foreach (string sqlServer in sqlServers)
        {
            comboBoxTargetServer.Items.Add(sqlServer);
        }

        //ActiveForm.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        comboBoxTargetDatabase.Enabled = true;            
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're clearing all of the items once the ComboBox has dropped down.  That will empty it, so there's nothing in the DropDown, so the list will disappear.  You should pick a different event to fill it.  In fact, is the data static within the context of one run of the application?  If so, fill the ComboBox on Form Load and leave it at that.

Comment: The combo is refilled in the foreach loop. That isn't the issue - the combo box is snapping closed once it's populated. I see it briefly onscreen and can still select items using the mouse wheel or cursor keys. The combo box behaved as you'd expect until I moved elements around on the form, but I haven't changed any code.

Comment: Hmm.. You're right about the clear not being the issue.  Just tried it in an application myself.  What else is in your form?

Comment: Well what are the other functions / functionality that you have added to the form.. perhaps you should work from the bottom up meaning start with the last thing that you added until you can narrow it down to the function/methods that are not acting as expected

Comment: also since you moved some of the form elements around.. check the TabIndex of the controls without seeing any of your code it would be hard to determine if you are doing some OnLeave or OnExit type of events.. I would check there first events when you leave the controls on your form..

Comment: I've rolled back the code to before I started messing with it and it still misbehaves! I'm going to try and get .net or the server restarted and see if that fixes it.